# How to expose Shoelace icons in a Vite app?

Tags: vite, rollup, pwabuilder, shoelace

The PWABuilder starter comes with Shoelace, which has a library of icons, but they don't seem to work out of the box:

````
import '@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/components/icon/icon.js';

@customElement('app-index')
export class AppIndex extends LitElement {

  // ...
  render() {
    return html```
      <sl-icon name="0-circle-fill"></sl-icon>
    ```;
  }
````

shows an empty icon.

The [Shoelace doc](https://shoelace.style/getting-started/installation?id=bundling) mentions the need to configure the bundler and `basePath` but doesn't come with an example of Vite config.

The icons in question are all bundled in the Shoelace package in node_modules: `node_modules/@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/assets/`, so I guess it's just a matter of configuring Vite to make those accessible as public assets, but it's really not obvious how.

How to make Shoelace icons work with Vite? More generally, how to make node_modules assets accessible to a Vite-bundled app?

Answer (score 4):

Found a way using the `vite-plugin-static-copy` plugin:

```
npm i -D vite-plugin-static-copy
```

Then in `./vite.config.ts`, add the following `viteStaticCopy` entry at the top of the `plugins:` array:

```
import { viteStaticCopy } from 'vite-plugin-static-copy'

// ...

export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  plugins:
    // ADD THIS
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        {
          src: 'node_modules/@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/assets/icons/*.svg',
          dest: 'shoelace/assets/icons'
        }
      ]
    }),
    // ...
```

This will make your icons available in `/shoelace/assets/icons/`.

Then in your JS code, e.g. in `src/app-index.js`, add:

```
import { setBasePath } from '@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/utilities/base-path.js';
setBasePath('/shoelace');
```

This will tell Shoelace to look for those assets in `/shoelace`.

Comment: The `setBasePath` example may not work in case of building the application with a non-empty prefix. A more reliable variant is `setBasePath( import.meta.env.BASE_URL + "shoelace/" );` which is working in VitePress as well as in a custom Vue3 application. For the icon configuration, I copy whole assets folder instead of being too picky here by focusing on SVG icons ... currently there are SVG icons, only. If, in future, Shoelace decides to put additional assets there they are supposedly meant to be published in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

import { setBasePath } from '@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/utilities/base-path.js';

setBasePath("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@shoelace-style/shoelace@2.14.0/cdn/");